# How to push view and data to different file?

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push data to `SDWebImageDataSource` file and push view to `SDWebImageRootViewController` with the code below. But I have a problem that imageLink(string) becomes null in the next `SDWebImageDataSource` but it push view to `SDWebImageRootViewController`.

Where would be my issue?

```
- (void)showSDWebImageView
{
  SDWebImageDataSource *imageController = [[SDWebImageDataSource alloc] init];
  imageController.imageLink = string1;
  NSLog(@"imagelink are: %@", imageController.imageLink);
  [imageController release];


  SDWebImageRootViewController *newController = [[SDWebImageRootViewController alloc] init];
  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
  [newController release];
}
```

`SDWebImageDataSource`.h

```
@property (nonmatic, retain) NSString *imageLink;
```

`SDWebImageDataSource`.m

```
@synthesize imageLink;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you can use method to pass the data, like the following.

```
SDWebImageDataSource *imageController = [[SDWebImageDataSource alloc] init];
[imageController setImageLink:string1];
```

In you SDWebImageDataSource class, you can get the data from that method,

```
-(void)setImageLink:(NSString *)imageLinkStr
{
   imageLink = imageLinkStr;
}
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: When I NSLog the imageLink I can see the value but I can't use imageLink(string) in other field. For example I can't use that data in another void. Could you help me please

Comment: You should assign that value to local variable.

Comment: I have did that, h.@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageLink; m.@synthesize imageLink; - (id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) { NSLog(@"imagelink is: %@", imageLink); }                 nil];
   }
   return self;
} imageLink result is null. How can I fix that?